# CSS - How to crop an image to a square, if it's already square then resize it

Tags: html, css, crop

Let's say that I have an image with `250 width and 250 height` and I want to crop it to `90x90`

It will show me pixels from the image, but I want to crop it if it is rectangle and resize it if it's square, So how can I do it?

This is the CSS code that crops the image, but how do I resize it?

```
.image{ 
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
}
.image{
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden;
    clip:rect(0px,90px,90px,0px);
}
```

Comment: I mean when it's square resize it to small square

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### METHOD 1

Will work for horizontal rectangle images (larger in width), if you need vertical images you can change `height:100%` for `width:100%`

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-container {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-container img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9efQj/)** First image is resized, second is cropped

### METHOD 2

Works for all image sizes

**HTML**

```
<div class="img" style="background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/250/250')"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img{
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9efQj/3/)**

Comment: That was great, but still only one problem now if the height is 720 and width 120 the size changed but not to a square, it changed to a rectangle, I tried `width: 100%;` it was fixed but the opposite happened. is there any way to do both height and width? By the way Thanks, for your great effort :)

Comment: @KevinMartin method 1 will only work for one of the other, with method 2 you can have both, I updated the second fiddle because for some reason it was the same as the first

Comment: If you know if an img is one or the other you could have two classes that implement method 1, one with height:100% and the other with width:100%. With method 2 you just have the limitation of browser support for `background-size`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div style="width:90px; height:90px; overflow:hidden;">
<img src="Message.png"/>
</div>
```