# How to center and crop an image to always appear in square shape with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to always crop a random-sized image to a square 160x160 using only CSS.
The images should stay centered when cropped.

My markup should be:

```
<a href="#" class="cropper">
   <img src="image" alt="description" />
</a>
```

Searching on StackOverflow I've found some answers (such as [CSS - How to crop an image to a square, if it's already square then resize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745559/css-how-to-crop-an-image-to-a-square-if-its-already-square-then-resize-it)), but they don't work for cases where your image can be larger horizontal (wide) *OR* vertical (tall).

Specifically, I need to be able to present both a wide image like this:

[image: wide image]

and a tall image like this:

[image: tall image]

in square form, without knowing in advance which one is a horizontal rectangle or a vertical rectangle. It should also support already squared images.

Comment: Propably not the answer you are looking for, but why not give `background-size:cover` a try?

Comment: Can it be cropped into fixed sizes?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/J7a5R/2/

Comment: @Itay yes sorry should be cropped to a fixed size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167545/how-to-crop-a-rectangular-image-into-a-square-with-css?rq=1

Comment: @SachinG it uses background proprieties, I need an img tag

Comment: @Itay it doesn't work, I've replied to his question with a fiddle,a nd by the way it doesn't center the image.

Comment: it doesn't center the images..

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/J7a5R/10/)

```css
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000%;
    right: -1000%;
    top: -1000%;
    bottom: -1000%;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/TwFrQXrP/plus-2.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

## A note regarding sizes

As [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a) mentioned in the comments,  we need to set the *img*'s position coordinates (top, left, bottom, right) to work with percents higher than the image's actual dimensions. I use *1000%* in the above example, but of course you can adjust it according to your needs.

[image: Before and after the fix]

* Further explanation: When we set the *img*'s *left* and *right* (or: *top* and *bottom*) coordinates to be *-100%* (of the containing *div*), the overall allowed *width* (or: *height*) of the *img*, can be at most *300%* of the containing *div*'s *width* (or: *height*), because it's the sum of the *div*'s width (or: *height*) and the *left* and *right* (or: *top* and *bottom*) coordinates.

Comment: I need to make them to fit the "thumbnail" space

Comment: If images are larger than div, you should better `width: 100%` for portrait images or `height: 100%` for landscape ones to the img tag.

Comment: Does it work if the image is larger than 300% of the div size? [I don't think so. FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/J7a5R/465/)

Comment: @SalmanA You're right. But it works decently otherwise. I guess it can be improved.

Comment: @Itay just use large (but sensible) number instead of 100%.

Answer (score 53):

`object-fit` property does the magic. On [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnk7oc6u/1/).

**CSS**

```
.image {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

.object-fit_fill {
  object-fit: fill
}

.object-fit_contain {
  object-fit: contain
}

.object-fit_cover {
  object-fit: cover
}

.object-fit_none {
  object-fit: none
}

.object-fit_scale-down {
  object-fit: scale-down
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="original-image">
  <p>original image</p>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>

<div class="image">
  <p>object-fit: fill</p>
  <img class="object-fit_fill" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>

<div class="image">
  <p>object-fit: contain</p>
  <img class="object-fit_contain" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>

<div class="image">
  <p>object-fit: cover</p>
  <img class="object-fit_cover" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>

<div class="image">
  <p>object-fit: none</p>
  <img class="object-fit_none" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>

<div class="image">
  <p>object-fit: scale-down</p>
  <img class="object-fit_scale-down" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
</div>
```

**Result**

[image: How the rendered images look (in a browser that supports <code>object-fit</code>)]

Comment: It's definitely the way to go unless you really need IE support. Even then, it's probably better just to inform your users they need to switch to a modern browser...

Comment: Great to know that this exists! Let's hope full cross-browser compatibility soon.

Answer (score 16):

```
<div>
    <img class="crop" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200"/>
</div>

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200"/>




div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.crop {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100%;
    right: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    bottom: -100%;
    margin: auto; 
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7a5R/56/

Comment: Just perfect, this will be the correct answer I think

Comment: This solution does not work when using images out of the scale `500x200`/`250x100`

Answer (score 8):

With the caveat of it not working in IE and some older mobile browsers, a simple `object-fit: cover;` is often the best option.

```
.cropper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cropper img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Without the `object-fit: cover` support, the image will be stretched oddly to fit the box so, if support for IE is needed, I'd recommend using one of the other answers' approach with `-100%` top, left, right and bottom values as a fallback.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your image into a container like so:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.testimoniesofheavenandhell.com/Animal-Pictures/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Dog-Animal-Picture-Siberian-Husky-Puppy-HD-Wallpaper.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div > img
{
    width: 300px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7a5R/4/).

Comment: @PurpleFoxy It would work best with a more square image, guess you'd need to play with the dimensions a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`clip` property with `position` may help you

```
a{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,0px);
}

a img{
position:relative;
left:-50%;
top:-50%;
 }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A8wwm/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I found a better solutions in following link. Only use **"object-fit"**
https://medium.com/@chrisnager/center-and-crop-images-with-a-single-line-of-css-ad140d5b4a87

Comment: It's worth noting this is not supported in IE

Comment: This is more or less just repeating [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35063374).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="specify your dimension:overflow:hidden">
    <div style="margin-top:-50px">
       <img ...  />
    </div>
</div>
```

The above will crop 50px from the top of the image.  You may want to compute to come up wit a top margin that will fit your requirements based on the dimension of the image.

To crop from the bottom simply specify the height of the outer div and remove the inner div.  Apply the same principle to crop from the sides.

Comment: In this way I need to know if the image is rectangular or horizontal and I also need to know how many pixel I need to move the image. Is not a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail { 
background: url(image.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat; /* 50% 50% centers image in div */
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 answer

```css
img {
  width: 200px; /* Determines square size */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* Will keep height equal to width */
  object-fit: cover; 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkGvg.jpg" />
```