# CSS: Crop image vertically centered with max height of 200px;

Tags: html, css

I want to crop an image with any natural dimension and give it a width of 100% and a maximum height of 200px usging CSS only.

After reading a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673900/how-to-center-and-crop-an-image-to-square-with-css), I'm close to it, but still the image is stretched horizontally.

HTML:

```
<div class="moduleItemIntrotext"> <a class="moduleItemImage" href="/gestao/item/7479-o-que-é-o-zero-working-capital-e-o-que-pode-beneficiar-com-isso.html" title="Continue a ler &quot;O que é o Zero Working Capital? (e o que pode beneficiar com isso)&quot;">
                      <img src="http://www.portal-gestao.com/media/k2/items/cache/x99c309f8b22ccf674ef513c2b1fdd8b5_XL.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Me394YWuwk.jpg" alt="O que é o Zero Working Capital? (e o que pode beneficiar com isso)" width="900" height="900">
          </a>

    <p>O working capital (ou fundo de maneio) é a diferença entre o ativo corrente e passivo corrente. Numa empresa com capacidade para encarar as suas obrigações financeiras de curto-prazo, o ativo corrente supera o passivo corrente. Se essa empresa necessitasse, poderia converter todo o seu ativo corrente em dinheiro e assim liquidar todas as suas dívidas de curto-prazo.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.moduleItemIntrotext {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.moduleItemIntrotext img {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/6k5trvr4/3/)

Comment: But if the image is larger than the div, how will the text appear below it without appearing outside of the div? Also, by positioning the image absolutely, you remove it from the flow of the document, which is why the text starts at the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is another possibility, keeping image into the flow and the HTML:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6k5trvr4/9/)**

line-height + negative-margin to virtually reduce height needed to lay the image.

```
.moduleItemIntrotext img {
    position: relative;
    margin: -50% auto;/* virtualy height needed turn don to zero */
    width: 100%;/* height will follow within image ratio */
    height:auto;/* to overrride attribute height set in tag */
    vertical-align:middle;/* finalise vertical centering on baseline*/
}
.moduleItemImage {
    display:block;
    height:200px;/*set an height */
    line-height:200px;/* set the baseline at 100px from top*/
    overflow:hidden;/* crops/cut off */
}
```

---

**Edit** : Nowdays, `object-fit` & `object-position` work fine .

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position

CSS becomes simple :

```css
.moduleItemIntrotext {

}
.moduleItemIntrotext img {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
.moduleItemIntrotext p {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="moduleItemIntrotext"> <a class="moduleItemImage" href="/gestao/item/7479-o-que-é-o-zero-working-capital-e-o-que-pode-beneficiar-com-isso.html" title="Continue a ler &quot;O que é o Zero Working Capital? (e o que pode beneficiar com isso)&quot;">
                     <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="O que é o Zero Working Capital? (e o que pode beneficiar com isso)" width="900" height="900">
          </a>

    <p>O working capital (ou fundo de maneio) é a diferença entre o ativo corrente e passivo corrente. Numa empresa com capacidade para encarar as suas obrigações financeiras de curto-prazo, o ativo corrente supera o passivo corrente. Se essa empresa necessitasse, poderia converter todo o seu ativo corrente em dinheiro e assim liquidar todas as suas dívidas de curto-prazo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking better! But it is still stretching vertically a bit, I think

Comment: @NunoNogueira oups, forgot about the attributes : here an update : http://jsfiddle.net/6k5trvr4/8/

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/72ppd7qL/.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href=""></a>
    <p>
        O working capital (ou fundo de maneio) é a diferença entre o ativo corrente e         
        passivo corrente. Numa empresa com capacidade para encarar as suas obrigações 
        financeiras de curto-prazo, o ativo corrente supera o passivo corrente. Se essa 
        empresa necessitasse, poderia converter todo o seu ativo corrente em dinheiro e 
        assim liquidar todas as suas dívidas de curto-prazo.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div > a {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(http://www.portalgestao.com/media/k2/items/cache/x99c309f8b22ccf674ef513c2b1fdd8b5_XL.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Me394YWuwk.jpg)
                no-repeat
                center center/cover;
}
```

Comment: lorem ipsum dolor, nice. Behavior similar to an SVG.