# how to make square cropped images responsive

Tags: css, image, crop, responsive

I am trying to crop a set of images of slightly varying sizes to be squares of matching sizes and make them responsive. I found that it's possible to crop my images by putting them in div's and then making the image a background image, but when I try to use height: auto to get responsive images, the div collapses.

This is the closest thing I can find to my problem:
[How to make centre cropped image responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567277/how-to-make-centre-cropped-image-responsive)

but this solution can only get a square crop if the image is in a portrait orientation to begin with. Additionally, I would have to hand-crop every image according to it's size.

I guess what I am looking for is a CSS hack that could crop all my images to be the same size square and then responsively scale them. Is this wishful thinking for CSS?

Comment: did u try max-width property?

Comment: Yes. I've set it up with max-width: 100%

Comment: I was working on a project yesterday and added this code for getting my image responsive ( I had bootstrap incorporated in the project ) so you may try my code and see if it works for you as well .. .about-image .class-name img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 28em;
}

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the background-size:cover? it adjust the background image to the size of the container..

```
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
```