# CSS crop image to fit screen width while keeping the original height of the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display an image (6000px width, 300px height) at the end of the `main-content` like background image. The image should fit the width of the screen, but keep the origin height.

In other words somehow always crop the image at the center while the width of the x-crop is the screen width size and height crop is the origin height of the image.

I have made the image with 6000px width so that I can fit all the screens.

the code below does not work as expected its obvious, it just display the original img while scaling the height to keep the aspect ratio relative to the screen width.

newnewwaves.svg : http://svgshare.com/i/3DT.svg

how I want to be displayed: https://ibb.co/e80Ddw

HTML:

```
<div class="main-content">
       ...content
        <div id="header-waves">
            <img src="/assets/images/newnewwaves.svg" alt="">
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-content {
   position: relative;
}
#header-waves {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
}
#header-waves img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: quick question is this an actual image, or more of a repeating background?

Comment: it is an actual image ( waves ) the image intention is to be used as background. at the end of an element

Comment: Why not add it as a background image with CSS??

Comment: becasue i don't think i can use clip-path if needed, i guess for my purpose i have manipulate inline clip-path with javascript based on debounced window resize event

Comment: User overflow:hidden property for your img ?

Comment: You could use `width: 0%`, but I am not sure this will work, even with `display: flex`

Comment: `#header-waves { width: 100%; } #header-waves img { max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: Have you tried putting a height="300px" attribute in your img tag and put overflow hidden in your css?

Comment: You could set image as background for #header-waves and set background-size: cover; background-position: center. But I am not sure you get 100% result you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to center and Crop an image to square with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673900/how-to-center-and-crop-an-image-to-square-with-css)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.img-class {

    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    object-fit: cover; 
}
```

This will help in maintaining aspect ration by restricting the width and cropping the image to center it.

If that doesn't work, Please try this :

```
.img-class {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px; /* Set your fixed Limit */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place the image in a container with `width: 100%` and set the overflow property to hidden.

Use `flexbox` to center the image within this container.

Note that this snippet is easier to test if you make it full screen and resize the browser...

```css
#header-waves {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <div id="header-waves">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/6000x300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working as expected will attach images so that its more clear

Comment: @GeorgiAntonov Ok, it's difficult to help any further based on an image alone. The website you've linked is calculating height dynamically and is more complex than the snippet.

Comment: Hi thanks I was able to get this to work for my use case by also applying **object-fit: cover;** to the img element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using background: url(...), like the example..

```css
.main-content
{
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/6000x300');
  background-size: auto 100%;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
       ...content
 </div>
```

Comment: I dont want to set height of the .main-content since its an flex element and its height is reproduced relative to its siblings

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
      <img
      src={userImageUrl}
      alt={userName}
      style={{
        borderRadius: "50%",
        width: "50px",
        height: "50px",
        objectFit: "cover",
      }}
```

I set the `height` and `width` both as I needed, and then added added `objectFit: "cover"` which helped fix it.